# Angular 2 carousel

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, property-binding

[UPDATE]
I work with angular 2 carousel which is here:

https://embed.plnkr.co/ScE0uqfd0ZvL6T9j1XjL/

I wanna add transition effect.

In carousel-example ts I added property

```
<carousel [interval]="NextPhotoInterval" [noWrap]="noLoopSlides" [noTransition]="noTrans">
```

noTrans property I declared inside carousel-example.ts as private noTrans:boolean = false;

noTransition is inside carousel component as

```
 @Input() public noTransition:boolean;
```

(where noTrans is false by default which by documentation should enable transitions).

This didn't do anything and I cant see any transition. Does anyone know where I'm wrong?

Thanks!

In the end I implemented my generic carousel using bootstrap, so I will post how I did it, in order to help if someone wants to use it:

component.html:

```
   <div id="carousel-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" *ngIf="newsData">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators" [hidden]="newsData.length <=1">
                <li data-target="#carousel-generic" *ngFor="let news of newsData; let i= index" attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(news)}"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner news-loading" role="listbox">
                <div *ngFor="let news of newsData;" class="item" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(news)}">
                    <h4 class="center">{{news.Title}}</h4>
                    <img class="img-responsive" [src]="news.ImageUrl">
                    <div class="news">
                        <p><a target="_blank" href="{{news?.DetailsUrl}}">{{news.Text}}</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev" [hidden]="!newsData.length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="next" [hidden]="!newsData.length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/component.html'
})

export class NewsComponent implements OnInit{
   private newsData: NewsDataModel[];

    constructor(private _service: MyService) {}

    private isActive(news:any){
       return news === this._service.newsData[0]; 
    }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.newsData = this._service.newsData;
  } 
}
```

*I did subscribe() in my service

Comment: I don't see any reference to `noTransition` in the code besides at declaration.

Comment: noTransition is inside carousel.component .ts as  @Input() public noTransition:boolean;

Comment: I'm saying that there is no other reference to it in the code. where is the documentation for this carousel?

Comment: documentation: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: Hey @HermioneGranger how did you solve the problem with transition in angular2 carousel ? I also want to do add the transitions to the carousel.

Comment: @Monica, in the end, I didn't use this component. I made my generic carousel using bootstrap. It works smooth and it's much simpler :)

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can see how I did it.